# Proof with trees

Tags: proof-verification, trees

Prove that every graph in which each vertex has degree at least 2 must contain a cycle.

This was my idea behind it but wasn't sure if I was on right track and how to move forward

If a graph is a tree with n >= 2 vertices , it has at least two vertices of degree one.

Contrapositive: if a graph with n>=2 vertices does not have at least two vertices of degree one, it is not a tree.

Comment: What is the definition of *tree* that you're using? (By the way, the graph should also have only finitely many vertices for what you want to prove to be true!)

Comment: Try drawing an example graph on paper. Start at any vertex. Take any edge and follow that to the next vertex, then mark that edge with an X. Then pick another edge that isn't marked with an X. this will be possible because each vertex has degree at least 2, 1 of which will be X'ed from earlier. Follow to the next vertex and X the edge. Repeat until you stumble upon a vertex you have been to. Now you have a cycle! Now try to think about why it happened.

Comment: All you have shown is that it is not a tree, you haven't show that there is a cycle, yet. A set of isolated vertices is not a tree, and does not have a cycle either.

Comment: An interesting generalization: any graph in which each vertex has degree 3 must contain a cycle with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a path of the maximum length possible, let it be $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_k$.

Since the path is of maximum length all of the neighbours of $a_1$ are in the path (otherwise there would be a longer path $x,a_1,\dots, a_k$ where $x$ is another neighbour of $a_1$.

Since the degree of $a_1$ is more than $1$ there is a vertex $a_j$ with $j>2$ that is connected to $a_1$.

Thus $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k,a_1$ is the desired cycle.

Comment: Fernandez Hidalgo is that all you need for the proof ?

Comment: yup ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$